# Error in accessing SQL Server in azure

Tags: azure, shiny-server

We could access the SQL Server in Azure, we could create a database, fetch data in shiny web app server using R and local system.

Suddenly we are now getting the following error

> [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 17, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

The connection string that we are using is

```
connectionString <-"Driver={SQL Server};Server=tcp:makarandsystems.database.windows.net,1433;Database=makarandsystems;Uid=srinivaskumar98@makarandsystems;Pwd={-};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

Also we are getting the following error when we deploy on webapp on shiny server
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

Can someone please help us with regard to these connection issues?

Comment: Did your IP address change (and is the new IP not in the allow list in the SQL Server firewall)?

Comment: What we  observed is that at server there is constant client IP....which is different from that of the system we are using

Comment: Today the connectivity to mssqlserver is there by deploying the code on the  shiny appserver which is installed in local machine which is running on windows operating system....however if we install it in the shinyaps.io server then there is a connectivity problem.Same old datasource name not found error persists?Can some one help?

Comment: Adding the ipaddress in the firewall resolves the issue